# Range queries for mongodb using morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am currently using morphia to construct my query(mongodb) as follows(reconstructed with some minor variations)

```
 Query<myClass> query = datastore.createQuery(myClass.class).filter("meta",objectID);
 List<Criteria> l = new ArrayList<>();
 for (loop on different values of min and max) {
  Criteria arrayA = query.and(query.criteria("price").greaterThanOrEq(min), query.criteria("price").lessThanOrEq(max)); //max and min are double
  l.add(arrayA);
   }
  query.or(l.toArray(new Criteria[]{}));
```

Above query when parsed is equivalent to -

```
{"m" : { "$oid" : "56186a51e4b0b33967940961"} , "$or" : [ { "$and" : [ { "p" : { "$gte" : 5000.0}} , { "p" : { "$lte" : 1.0E9}}]}]}
```

I have recently realised this query doesn't use index properly and it is instead better to use query in this format

```
{"m" : { "$oid" : "56186a51e4b0b33967940961"} , "$or" : [ { "$and" : [ { "p" : { "$gte" : 5000.0, "$lte" : 1.0E9}}]}]}
```

I have confirmed using `mongo console`(and explain) that second query although similiar does perform extremely better for large datasets. But I am unable to find an equivalent code in morphia to construct this `mongo query`. Can somebody please help me here with the correct syntax to construct this exact query, mentioned later, in morphia if possible. Or else please suggest me an alternative java wrapper instead of morphia which can provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with Morphia — you're looking for a kind of "between" method.

Either give http://jongo.org a try (which is basically a wrapper around the MongoDB shell in Java) or provide the output of the explain. Maybe it can be tuned in another way.